# How to place text below image which is centred(both horizontally and vertically) inside <div>

Tags: html, css

Currently the text is show on top of div , I want it below the image.I am unable to do it.

```css
.modal-body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

#img {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <img id="img" style="width:30%;" src="logo.png" />
  <p style="text-align:center;color:3b3b3b;display:block;top:60%;">My text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use flex-box:

```css
.modal-body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
background-color:white;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

#img{
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
<img id="img" style="width:30%;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/" />
<p style="text-align:center;color:3b3b3b;display:block;top:60%;">My text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: sir this is working but there is a lot of space at the bottom of image and text, it is giving equal spacing at top and bottom of image, as result text is almost at bottom of div

Comment: I solved this by making a div of 50 percent height placed image at the bottom and place text below the div

Answer (score 1):

Remove the position:absolute from the CSS

Also try putting div /div around the image img and the p elements.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div>
      <img id="img" style="width:30%;" src="logo.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
       <p style="text-align:center;color:3b3b3b;display:block;top:60%;">My text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```